# Are trades routes and/or mountain routes still used?

Tags: hiking, trekking

**Some background:**

I live in the western part of state of Maharashtra, India. The city of Pune is located on the [Deccan Plateau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deccan_Plateau).
Deccan plateau itself is huge. The western section of the plateau has a vertical drops of ranging from about 900 to 1800 ft. for about 1600 km. This section is what known to world as [The Western Ghats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Ghats)

So, there are trails from villages located on Deccan plateau to the lower  places, popularly called [Kokan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konkan). 
In Maharashtra there are 250+ such routes that are documented, and about 100+ which aren't documented. Before the development age, some of these were used for trade and commute.

**My observation:**
What I have observed is due to lack of development in economy almost 75% of villagers still frequent these routes down the mountain, be it for trade, or be it for travelling. The road transport is there, but these foot-trails are still the shorter (and free, of course) way of commute.

The point is, these routes are not limited to trekking/hiking only!

**Question:**
Are there such routes in the part of the world where you live? I agree that those route may not be used for trade these days, but do people use these routes for commuting by foot? I don't want to consider such paths that are converted into motor-able highways/freeways/roads.

Comment: You mean for trade purposes? Obviously the routes are well known trekking/hiking routes.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Surely you are not asking whether there are historical trade routes which are still used today all over the world, because that answer would be: I can't prove it, but of course there are. I am probably missing something specific.

Comment: @imsodin: I am actually asking that.

Comment: On rereading I see that my comment was kind of passive aggressive - sorry for that, wasn't my intention. My issue is, that this question is extremely broad, i.e. nobody can answer a question for the entire world. And at least in the areas I know, historic trade routes are either still important traffic routes, or hiking paths. Mankind has increased, not decreased, so while there probably are some abandoned paths, I'd say in general there are more, not less paths.

Comment: @imsodin even i felt the same. I thought I could answer for India, but then the question is across the world.

Comment: In the US many of the paths have been converted to Multilane highways. I am adding my vote to close as too broad. FYI see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oregon_Trail

Comment: Hi Weda - while interesting, I think this does qualify as too broad, unfortunately

Comment: @Rory: Not a problem :-)

Comment: See [Old Georgetown Pike](https://scenicbyways.info/byway/10304.html).  The herds mentioned in the article were buffalo.  It is still used for commuting today, and I used to walk from my house to the shopping center along it, but there are so many Jaguars on it today that hiking is dangerous. :)

Comment: See this article on England's [Ridgeway Trail](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/11/01/travel/01ridgeway.html)

Comment: Shame to throw out [questions like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/323334/60679). It could have turned into a very interesting community wiki.